# jquery ajax form submit not working properly in IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I gave up on trying to use onblur or focusout to submit the form because that forced a page refresh. Now I use a button and it uses a ajax post and clears the qty field as the item is added.

My problem now, is that IE8 isn't playing well with this solution.

```
$('.qty').change('input[type=text]').val('');
```

This works in FF, Chrome and Safari, but doesn't work in IE8. In IE8 when the user hits the add item button the form is submitted and the page refreshes. Obviously the ajax call is failing in IE8. I just can't figure out why. Do I need to prevent the default action before the .change call?

snippet from jcart-javascript.php

```
// SEND ITEM INFO VIA POST TO INTERMEDIATE SCRIPT WHICH CALLS jcart.php AND RETURNS         UPDATED CART HTML
//      $.post('<?php echo $jcart['path'];?>jcart-relay.php', { "<?php echo $jcart['item_id']?>": itemId, "<?php echo $jcart['item_price']?>": itemPrice, "<?php echo $jcart['item_name']?>": itemName, "<?php echo $jcart['item_qty']?>": itemQty, "<?php echo $jcart['item_add']?>" : itemAdd }, function(data) {
  $.post('<?php echo $jcart['path'];?>jcart-relay.php', postData, function(data) {
//JSTN-end

        // REPLACE EXISTING CART HTML WITH UPDATED CART HTML
        $('#jcart').html(data);
        $('.jcart-hide').remove();
        $('.qty').change('input[type=text]').val('');
        });

    // PREVENT DEFAULT FORM ACTION
    return false;

    });


// WHEN THE VISITOR HITS THEIR ENTER KEY
// THE UPDATE AND EMPTY BUTTONS ARE ALREADY HIDDEN
// BUT THE VISITOR MAY UPDATE AN ITEM QTY, THEN HIT THEIR ENTER KEY BEFORE FOCUSING ON ANOTHER ELEMENT
// THIS MEANS WE'D HAVE TO UPDATE THE ENTIRE CART RATHER THAN JUST THE ITEM WHOSE QTY HAS CHANGED
// PREVENT ENTER KEY FROM SUBMITTING FORM SO USER MUST CLICK CHECKOUT OR FOCUS ON ANOTHER ELEMENT WHICH TRIGGERS CHANGE FUNCTION BELOW
$('#jcart').keydown(function(e) {

    // IF ENTER KEY
    if(e.which == 13) {

    // PREVENT DEFAULT ACTION
    return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of returning `false` in your `keydown` handler, consider using `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **trigger** the submit event, use this:

```
$('form.jcart').submit();
```

I hope I got your intentions, becuase that code has a bad formatting and the question isn't clear enough.

Comment: I can get the form to submit with that line, but what I'm trying to do is to submit the input on focusout. without having to click the submit button or hit enter.

Comment: @Resq32: `$('form.cart input[type="text"].focusout(function(){$(this).closest('form').submit()});`

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. I'll get back at it later. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [blur](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CD4QFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/blur/&ei=ucmVT_j1N6iciQLz7Mm1Cg&usg=AFQjCNEjpXe7nDq6B_sTJHtz3Bc7ms0e3Q&sig2=ZgxHW3mXqyQ16vnX8W1VAw):

```
$('form.cart input[type=text]').blur(function(){
   $(this).parents('form').submit();
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. it forces a page refresh which puts the user back at the first page.   $('.qty').change('input[type=text]').val(''); works for all browsers but IE8 the item is added and the page doesn't refresh.

Comment: Yes, because it submits the form on blur, which is exactly what your question title says you want to do.  If that's not what you want, what DO you want?  Work on your question - ask a specific question (one) and provide all relevant code.